# What does this makefile do?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile (Makefile.certify) and when I execute:

```
make -f Makefile.certify
```

It gives me a:

`/bin/sh: line 23: -o: command not found`

```
PROG=certify
TMP=/var/tmp
ARCH=x86_64
_CC=/bin/cc

all: ${PROG}

${PROG}: ${ARCH}
    @for mode in $? ; do \
            case $${mode} in        \
                    i386)           \
                            CC="${_CC} -g -D__x86";         \
                            ;;      \
                    i386-f64)       \
                            CC="${_CC} -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -D__x86";\
                            ;;      \
                    amd64)          \
                            CC="${_CC} -m64 -g -D__x86 -D__ia64 -D__GNUC";\
                            ;;      \
                    *)              \
                            ;;      \
            esac;           \
            $${CC} -o ${TMP}/$${mode}/$@ ${TMP}/$@.c;       \
    done
```

I don't really use `makefiles` or `c`, but I have to deal with this one.

**My questions are:**

> 1. Why does for loop need a `@` prefix?
> 2. What is the `$?` in the for loop?
> 3. What would be a possible execution of this makefile? Obviously it tries to compile my certify.`c file` based on the architecture of the system executing or something like this, but I fail to see how it will choose either `i386` or `amd64` etc.

I am using an `x86` system running `RHEL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `@` prefix is used for suppressing command print by `make`. If it is not present, `make` will print command before execution to output.

   You can remove it and see the difference.
2. `$?` is the dependency list. In your particular case `ARCH` is defined as a single entry "x86_64". So `$?` will be expanded into that value. But you can try to modify `ARCH` value in the following way:

   ```
    ARCH=x86_64 i386
   ```
3. It tries to build `certify` binary for a given architecture from `cerfify.c` source file. Each binary will be located in own sub-directory:

   ```
    /var/tmp/{i386|x86_64|i386_f64}/certify
   ```

Comment: Great. So right now it can't match "x86_64" to any cases, therefore "mode" variable is empty and compilation fails. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. `@` is used to suppress the normal 'echo' of the command that is executed. Using it in the for loop is also new to me (does removing it change anything in the output?)
2. `$?` is one of the [makefile automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html), this one means `"The names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target, with spaces between them"`
3. It will iterate through `$?`, read above

*Edit:*

Example of `$?`

```
targetfile : firstfile secondfile thirdfile
    cat $? > $@
```

if `targetfile` is **older than all the other 3 files**, the makefile will concatenate the contents of `firstfile`, `secondfile` and `thirdfile` together in `targetfile`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please share an example of `$?` ?

Comment: @Michael added a simple one, I think it illustrates the way `$?` works